# In Laravel many-to-many relationship, is there a way to update data in a pivot table?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

I built two models User and Institution.
How do I update the pivot data between them, after adding additional Pivot columns?

```
<?php

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function institutions()
    {
        $pivots = ['id', 'program_choice', 'session'];
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Institution')
            ->withPivot($pivots);
    }
}


class Institution extends Authenticatable
{

    public function users()
    {
        $pivots = ['id', 'program_choice', 'session'];
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'institution_user')
            ->withPivot($pivots);;
    }
}
```

Here are the migrations

```
class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

class CreateInstitutionsTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('institutions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name')->unique();
            $table->string('city')->nullable();
            $table->string('state')->nullable();
            $table->string('country')->nullable();
            $table->string('address')->nullable();
            $table->string('user_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('postal_code')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
}
```

This is the what the pivot table looks like

[image]
I am able to attach the information to the pivot table

```
public function storeInstitution(Request $request)
    {
        $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $user = User::find($user_id);
        $institution_id = $request->input('institution_id');
        $user_program_choice = $request->input('program_choice');
        $user_session = $request->input('session');
        $user_inst =   array(
            'program_choice' => $user_program_choice,
            'session'        => $user_session,
            'user_id'        => $user_id,
            'institution_id' => $institution_id
        );
        $user->institutions()->attach($institution_id, $user_inst);
        return 'success';
    }
```

But unable to update the attached pivot E.g I can't change  the program_choice, `particle physics` to something like `digital art`
Here's my current code

```
 public function updateInstitutions(Request $request, $pivot_id)#TODO id is pivot_id
    { 
        $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $user = User::find($user_id);
        $institution_id = $request->input('institution_id');
        $pivot_attributes =   array(
            'user_id'        => $user_id,
            'institution_id' => $institution_id,
            'session'        => $request->input('session'),
            'program_choice' => $request->input('program_choice'),
        );

        $user->institutions()->updateExistingPivots($institution_id, $pivot_attributes, false);
        return 'success';

    }
```

How do I update my pivot data, using the pivot id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-a-record-on-a-pivot-table) regarding this aspect.

> #### Updating A Record On A Pivot Table
>
> If you need to update an existing row in your pivot table, you may use
> `updateExistingPivot` method. This method accepts the pivot record
> foreign key and an array of attributes to update:
>
> ```
> $user = App\Models\User::find(1);
>
> $user->roles()->updateExistingPivot($roleId, $attributes);
> ```

Comment: The pivot has a primary key. is there a way to use the primary key, rather than the foreign key to update?

Comment: @jay4592 you could create a pivot model and just query the row directly from there. See https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models

Comment: Is there a book, video or article that covers the Pivot model extensively? Does it share the same behaviour as a normal Model? can I create controllers for it? Can I use the save() method for it?

Comment: @jay4592 the `Pivot` class extends the `Model` one (see [this](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/363dc94885590331ef0bf9106bf90be2dbe8fff6/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/Pivot.php#L8)), so yes.. same behavior.

Comment: Thanks. That's all I needed to know. It's reassuring.